# Print error message in console from DB2 procedure

Tags: console, db2

Is there any other simple way to print message in console from DB2 procedure without setting DB2_COMPATIBILITY_VECTOR=ORA in registry?

Comment: ...why do you want to output to a console?  Which console?  How do you plan on calling the procedure... and what's the complete chain?

Comment: the simple requirement is to copy table from one schema to another schema. Now I have written a procedure which takes 4 parameters 1. Source Schema, 2. Target Schema, 3. Source Table, 4. Target Table. and the intention is if user gives any wrong input like invalid source schema or invalid source table then procedure should throw error with proper error message. Now to show that error message I want to print in the console

Comment: ...um, wouldn't however you're running the statement be able to print any error codes you get already?  Most statement runners I'm aware of will squawk at you with whatever was thrown.  Plus, what happens when they're not running it through a regular console - say, it's in another procedure, called from an ORM instance, or running unattended anyways?  This is also relevant because there are existing codes for those elements being missing (although you need to throw them yourself as validation, or risk SQL Injection).  How are you planning on handling the individual data columns?

Comment: Please find below the sample code which I am trying.. it is currently throwing compilation errors .. `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE COPY_TABLE( IN SRC_SCMA VARCHAR(30), IN TGT_SCMA VARCHAR(30), IN SRC_TBL VARCHAR(50), IN TGT_TBL VARCHAR(50) ) LANGUAGE SQL CALLED ON NULL INPUT BEGIN DECLARE a INT; DECLARE d INT; SELECT COUNT(1) INTO a FROM SYSCAT.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMANAME = UCASE(''||SRC_SCMA||''); IF a <= 0 THEN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('Invalid Source Schema Specified'); END IF; END`

Comment: Okay, but that would be part of the question (or a different one), along with the actual error.  Regardless, I'm not convinced outputting to output like this is what you really want/need.  For one thing, you have to redirect it to an output stream, then have some way to read from that.  This is okay during debugging, but doesn't make much sense during normal operations.  If you have an error condition, you need to be throwing exceptions.  And how are you planning on calling this procedure?  What calls it, what calls that, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the built-in module [dbms_output](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.sqlpl.doc/doc/r0053551.html) allows printing to the console AND it can be used without setting the compatibility vector, you shoul be able to print the messages. I just tested this without a procedure on a V10.5 database:

```
[hloeser@mymachine]$ db2 "set serveroutput on"
DB20000I  The SET SERVEROUTPUT command completed successfully.
[hloeser@mymachine]$ db2 "call dbms_output.put('Hello')"

  Return Status = 0
[hloeser@mymachine]$ db2 "call dbms_output.new_line"

  Return Status = 0

Hello
```

It is important to enable [serveroutput](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0053562.html).

Comment: I am using the below code and it is throwing compilation error

Comment: `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE COPY_TABLE(
  IN SRC_SCMA VARCHAR(30),
  IN TGT_SCMA VARCHAR(30),
  IN SRC_TBL VARCHAR(50),
  IN TGT_TBL VARCHAR(50)
)
LANGUAGE SQL
CALLED ON NULL INPUT

BEGIN
 DECLARE a INT;
 DECLARE d INT;
 SELECT COUNT(1) INTO a FROM SYSCAT.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMANAME = UCASE(''||SRC_SCMA||'');
 IF a <= 0 THEN 
     DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT('Invalid Source Schema Specified');
 END IF;
 
END`

Comment: What is the error message, are you trying this with CLP or in a tool, ...? And you need the serveroutput switched on and you need to either use PUT_LINE or PUT+NEW_LINE to see any output (see the docs referenced in my answer).

Comment: I am using Aginity for Hadoop tool .. and this proc I am trying to write in BigSql 3.x .. where there is a DB2 db under the hood .. the error message is `ERROR [42601] [IBM][DB2/LINUXX8664] SQL0104N  An unexpected token "<variable declaration>" was found following "".  Expected tokens may include:  "<SQL statement>".`

Comment: Code is `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE COPY_TABLE1(
  IN SRC_SCMA VARCHAR(30),
  IN TGT_SCMA VARCHAR(30),
  IN SRC_TBL VARCHAR(50),
  IN TGT_TBL VARCHAR(50)
)
LANGUAGE SQL
CALLED ON NULL INPUT

BEGIN
 DECLARE a INT;
 DECLARE d INT;
 SELECT COUNT(1) INTO a FROM SYSCAT.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMANAME = UCASE(''||SRC_SCMA||'');
 IF a <= 0 THEN 
     CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Invalid Source Schema Specified');
 END IF;
END@`

Comment: Well, BigSQL is based on DB2, but it is a different product and has its own restrictions. You should have noted in the question. As you can see in the [BigInsights documentation for BigSQL, the module dbms_output](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSPT3X_4.0.0/com.ibm.swg.im.infosphere.biginsights.analyze.doc/doc/bi_admin_bigsql_defpriv.html) is present. So the error seems to be related to the procedure itself.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to achieve what I intended using the below steps:

```html
[user@boxname]/home/user>db2 "set serveroutput on"
DB20000I  The SET SERVEROUTPUT command completed successfully.
[user@boxname]/home/user>cat > copy_table
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE COPY_TABLE(
  IN SRC_SCMA VARCHAR(30),
  IN TGT_SCMA VARCHAR(30),
  IN SRC_TBL VARCHAR(50),
  IN TGT_TBL VARCHAR(50)
)
LANGUAGE SQL
CALLED ON NULL INPUT

BEGIN

DECLARE a INT;
DECLARE b INT;
DECLARE c INT;
DECLARE d INT;

SELECT COUNT(1) INTO a FROM SYSCAT.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMANAME = UCASE(''||SRC_SCMA||'');

IF a <= 0 THEN
    CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Invalid Source Schema Specified');
        GOTO LAST_BLOCK;
END IF;

SELECT COUNT(1) INTO b FROM SYSCAT.SCHEMATA WHERE SCHEMANAME = UCASE(''||TGT_SCMA||'');

IF b <= 0 THEN
    CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Invalid Target Schema Specified');
        GOTO LAST_BLOCK;
END IF;

SELECT COUNT(1) INTO c FROM SYSCAT.TABLES WHERE TABSCHEMA = UCASE(''||SRC_SCMA||'') AND TABNAME=UCASE(''||SRC_TBL||'');

IF c <= 0 THEN
    CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Invalid Target Schema Specified');
        GOTO LAST_BLOCK;
END IF;

SELECT COUNT(1) INTO d FROM SYSCAT.TABLES WHERE TABSCHEMA = UCASE(''||TGT_SCMA||'') AND TABNAME=UCASE(''||TGT_TBL||'');

IF d > 0
THEN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE '||TGT_SCMA||'.'||TGT_TBL;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE HADOOP TABLE '||TGT_SCMA||'.'||TGT_TBL||' AS SELECT * FROM '||SRC_SCMA||'.'||SRC_TBL;
        CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Invalid Source Table OR Source Schema & Table Combition Is Wrong');
ELSE
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE HADOOP TABLE '||TGT_SCMA||'.'||TGT_TBL||' AS SELECT * FROM '||SRC_SCMA||'.'||SRC_TBL;
        CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Target Table Created & Loaded');
END IF;

 LAST_BLOCK:
        RETURN;

END@
[user@boxname]/home/user>db2 -td@ -f copy_table
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

[user@boxname]/home/user>db2 "CALL COPY_TABLE('invalid_user','valid_user','TEST_TABLE','TEST_TABLE')"

  Return Status = 0

Invalid Source Schema Specified
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the console the send messages, you have to wait to the end of the execution. If you generate a message in a batch process, it could take a while to show the message.

If your execution is just one instruction and one error, you can 'raise a signal'. In this way, the error message could be retrieved from any application that access DB2.

Instead of printing the output in the console, which IMO is not a very good practice (only console is able to show the server output), you can write a message in a log. You can write the output in another table, or use a framework like log4db2.

By using a log mechanism like log4db2, if you execute this statement as part of a batch process, you can get the message just by querying the log table at any time, and you do not have to wait to the end of the execution.